# XOR -Is it possible to prove that if A=C⊕B then B=C⊕A and C=A⊕B using Boolean algebra only?

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

If you write out the truth tables then it's pretty simple, write the truth table for **A=C⊕B**, you can chose A, B or C to be the output and
you get a xor truth table with the remaining two as inputs, so if **A=C⊕B** then **B=C⊕A** and **C=A⊕B**

But I was wondering if there was a nicer proof using Boolean algebra only

Edit: **A=C⊕B** can be written as **A=(C'B)+(CB')**

Comment: probably more natural to think of it in $\mathbb F_2$(integers modulo $2$), here xor is simply addition. 

$A=B+C\implies A+B=B+C+B=C$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

$A=C \oplus B$

$\oplus A$ both sides. (Yes, you can do that).

$$A\oplus A = A\oplus C \oplus B$$

$$\implies FALSE = A\oplus C \oplus B$$

Now, $\oplus B$ both sides.

$$B \oplus FALSE = A\oplus C \oplus B \oplus B$$

(We are also using commutativity of $\oplus$ above)

$$B \oplus FALSE = A\oplus C \oplus FALSE$$

$$\implies B = A \oplus C$$.

Repeat similar construction for $C$.